# Meteor MCrypt app will not compile on heroku because it's missing libmcrypt4 etc

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor, mcrypt

I am trying to push a simple meteor application to heroku that uses the mcrypt package.

It works perfect on my local machine as i used brew to install mcrypt which included all of the dev libs.

However when pushing to heroku, mcrypt cannot compile. The error is:

```
In file included from ../src/mcrypt.cc:3:0:
../src/mcrypt.h:10:20: fatal error: mcrypt.h: No such file or directory
#include 
^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/mcrypt/src/mcrypt.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can make this work? thanks

Comment: Did you fix this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question in github, I imagine you're the same :)

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove libmcrypt4 libmcrypt-dev
```

and then reinstall mcrypt.

Comment: Sadly it's not enough, the only way to run apt-get is through the apt buildpack, and it still doesn't seem to recognise the libs. Can't even seem to confirm if they are installed.